# How to start Vue 3 transition on button only if server request takes more than 300 ms

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-livewire, inertiajs

I am working on a `Laravel` + `InertiaJS` + `Vue 3` project.

Specifically, I am working on a `DelayedTransition` Vue3 SFC which runs a `transition` only if the corresponding server request takes more than, e.g., 300 ms.

When I was using `Laravel` + `Livewire` + `AlpineJS`, this was a nice [core-feature](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/loading-states#delaying-loading) of Livewire, but I am not a Vue expert and I am really stuck with this. Can anyone suggest a smart way to achieve the described functionality inside de `DelayedTransition` SFC?

Thanks in advance.